# How to combine two NSDictionary in Swift

Tags: swift, dictionary

I am a beginner in swift and I am trying to apprehend the notion of dictionaries.

I have two NSDictionary that both contain the same keys, as follow:

```
var currencyname: NSDictionary = [
        "CNY": "Chinese Yuan",
        "PLN": "Polish Zloty"
]

var rawrates NSDictionary = [
        "CNY": "1.34",
        "PLN": "1.456"
]
```

I am trying to combine them so that I get only one Dictionary such as:

```
        ["CNY": "Chinese Yuan","1.34"]
        ["PLN": "Polish Zloty","1.456"]
```

I guess my first question is what sort of variable should I put the output in ? Can I use an NSDictionary ? From reading the documentation my understanding was that NSDictionaries work by pairs of Key/Values. Is it possible to put two values inside the dictionary ?

My Second question is how should I go about combining those two Dictionaries, I have tried to use the code below without much success

```
for (currency, rawrate) in rawrates {
                for (currencyid, name) in currencyname{
                    if currency == currencyid {
                        rawrates.append(name as String)
                    }
                } 
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create a dictionary of tuples as follow:

```
let currencyname:[String:String] = ["CNY": "Chinese Yuan", "PLN": "Polish Zloty"]
let rawrates:[String:String] = ["CNY": "1.34", "PLN": "1.456"]

var combinedDictionary:[String:(name:String,rate:String)] = [:]


for key in currencyname.keys.array {
    combinedDictionary[key] = (currencyname[key]!,rawrates[key]!)
}


// Testing

combinedDictionary["PLN"]!       // (.0 "Polish Zloty", .1 "1.456")
combinedDictionary["PLN"]!.name  // "Polish Zloty"
combinedDictionary["PLN"]!.rate  // "1.456"

combinedDictionary["CNY"]!       // (.0 "Chinese Yuan", .1 "1.34")
combinedDictionary["CNY"]!.name  // "Chinese Yuan"
combinedDictionary["CNY"]!.rate  // "1.34"
```

Comment: Tuple is a great option as well.  Certainly better than my first suggestion of an array.  Whether we use a tuple or a struct (or a class) depends on what all we intend to do with this information long term.

Comment: The information is just meant to be displayed in a tableview (for now at least). Considering that, do you recommend a specific method ?

Comment: If it will be displayed in a table view you just need to use the keys array as your table view data source.

Answer (score 1):

We can't quite combine dictionaries in this manner.  The problem is, a dictionary only allows one value per key.

The solution is to instead have a dictionary which looks something like this:

```
[
    "CNY" : ["Chinese Yuan","1.34"],
    "PLN" : ["Polish Zloty","1.456"]
]
```

So our keys are `"CNY"` and `"PLN"`, but each key has an *array* of values.

Here's one possible interpretation on combining your dictionaries:

```
var combinedDict = [String:Array<Any>]()
for key in currencyName.allKeys {
    combinedDict[key] = [currencyName[key], rawRates[key]]
}
println(combinedDict)
```

---

But honestly, what makes the most sense here is to probably simply make something to hold all of our currency information.

```
struct Currency {
    let name: String?
    let rawRate: String?
}
```

And now build a dictionary of these objects:

```
var currencyInformation = [String:Currency]()
for key in currencyName.allKeys {
    combinedDict[key] = Currency(name: currencyName[key], rawRate: rawRates[key])
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, I am not quite sure I understand what "struct Currency" does exactly ? does it just declare the structure of the array ?

Comment: No, it creates a `struct`, which is a data type.  There's not a short answer to explaining what a `struct` is, so I can only point you toward the official documentation to have a read up.

Comment: Instead of an Array, I would rather use a tuple if you dont want to make a struct

Comment: @Clashsoft I agree that an array is a pretty bad solution for this specific scenario, but it may make sense in some scenario.

Answer (score 0):

Another simple answer, using string interpolation and which is type safe:

```
var currencyName = ["CNY":"Chinese Yuan", "PLN": "Polish Zloty"]
var rawRates = ["CNY":"1.34" , "PLN":"1.456"]
var combined = [String:String]()

for (ccyCode, ccyName) in currencyName
{
    if let possibleRate = rawRates[ccyCode]
    {
        combined[ccyCode] = "\(ccyName), \(possibleRate)"
    }
    else
    {
        combined[ccyCode] = "\(ccyName), N/A"
    }     
}
```

Comment: Hmm, nevermind.  I was misreading it... I see what you're doing now.