# How to safely unwrap nil values in swift?

Tags: swift, dictionary

I am fairly new to swift and I am trying to understand how to deal with nil vars...

I have two Dictionaries:

```
var currencyname: NSDictionary = [
        "CNY": "Chinese Yuan",
        "PLN": "Polish Zloty"
        "EUR": "Euro"
]

var rawrates NSDictionary = [
        "CNY": "1.34",
        "PLN": "1.456"
]
```

I am combining them using a dictionary of tuples:

```
var combinedDictionary:[String:(name:String,rate:String)] = [:]

for key in currencyname.keys.array {
    combinedDictionary[key] = (currencyname[key]!,rawrates[key]!)
}
```

However I get a `found nil while unwrapping an Optional value` error since the key `EUR` in the `currencyname` Dictionary does not match any key in the `rawrate` dictionary.

I understand that I would have to somehow check that the key exists in both dictionary before combining them using `let if` ? But I am confused regarding the syntax ... I have also tried to use optional values without success.

So my question is how could I combine those two dictionaries and leave out `EUR` of combinedDictionary as there is no matching key in the `rawrate` Dictionary?

Thank you for your help!

Comment: "I have two arrays" No, you have two dictionaries. You won't get _anywhere_ until you get _that_ straight.

Comment: Oops you're right ! I edited my question

Comment: I think you should stop and state clearly, to yourself and to us, what you want the final result to look like. You don't seem to know what you want, so you have no way to get there, if you see what I mean.

Comment: No I end up with ["CNY" : ("Chinese Yuan", "1.34")] that works fine

Comment: Okay, but I'm still unclear what you want. A dictionary of tuples seems a really odd thing. You'd be better off making a custom Struct, in my opinion. A tuple is _not_ a good way to store data; it's meant just for handing multiple pieces of data from place to place. Anyway, see my answer, as far as it goes...

Comment: Thanks for your help, I am going to read up on customs Struct !

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to combine two NSDictionary in Swift](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30948326/how-to-combine-two-nsdictionary-in-swift)

Comment: @anto0522 The bottom half of my answer to your previous question used structs...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think what you're after is something like this:

```
    let currencyname = [
        "CNY": "Chinese Yuan",
        "PLN": "Polish Zloty",
        "EUR": "Euro"
    ]

    let rawrates = [
        "CNY": "1.34",
        "PLN": "1.456"
    ]

    var combinedDictionary = [String:(name:String,rate:String)]()
    for key in currencyname.keys {
        if let val1 = currencyname[key], val2 = rawrates[key] {
            combinedDictionary[key] = (val1,val2)
        }
    }
```

But it's a little hard to be sure without a clearer problem statement. This isn't something I would advise in any case. This seems to me to be a better outcome:

```
let currencyname = [
    "CNY": "Chinese Yuan",
    "PLN": "Polish Zloty",
    "EUR": "Euro"
]

let rawrates = [
    "CNY": "1.34",
    "PLN": "1.456"
]

struct Currency {
    let name : String
    let rate : String
}

var combinedDictionary = [String:Currency]()
for key in currencyname.keys {
    if let val1 = currencyname[key], val2 = rawrates[key] {
        combinedDictionary[key] = Currency(name:val1, rate:val2)
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you, That works. I'm pretty sure my problem was stated probably ie: "So my question is how could I combine those two dictionaries and leave out EUR of combinedDictionary as there is no matching key in the rawrate Dictionary?"

Comment: @anto0522 Why not try using my answer to your previous question, which is quite similar to matt's answer here, but with a subtle difference. http://stackoverflow.com/a/30948414/2792531

Comment: @nhgrif Hi ! I did actually use your answer. This question was about how to unrwrap nil values with a "if let" expression I was just using the example I used before to illustrate my problem ... I wasn't sure about wether to ask on my previous question or to create a new one so I went with creating a new one ...

Comment: The suggested advice would actually be to spend more than 2 seconds playing around in Xcode and apply a little logic to the problem.  There are *tons* of questions about dealing with optionals and unwrapping.  You're sprinting to Stack Overflow apparently the instant you run into the slightest problem seemingly without spending much effort on your own.  We will tire of it soon (even this question has negative votes).

Comment: @nhgrif is right. You should _learn_ Swift before you _use_ it. Don't waste our time and bandwidth with this sort of elementary stuff.

Comment: "You should learn swift before you use it" I guess that's easy to say for you guys and your 100K+ gold medals. For someone like me learning by myself, websites like stack overflow are my only chance to understand swift beyond the documentation and online tutorials. I thought this was a place where ppl like you could help ppl like me. I'm sorry I waisted your time and valuable bandwith ... Have a good day

Comment: "beyond the documentation and online tutorials" But the documentation and online tutorials _cover_ this. So it's more like you _didn't_ look at the documentation and online tutorials.