# Concatenate two dictionaries in Swift

Tags: swift, dictionary, concatenation

Swift gives us plenty new abilities like (at last!) concatenating strings and even arrays. But no support for dictionaries. Is the only way to concatenate dictionaries is to overload + operation for them?

```
let string = "Hello" + "World" // "HelloWorld"
let array = ["Hello"] + ["World"] // ["Hello", "World"]
let dict = ["1" : "Hello"] + ["2" : "World"] // error =(
```

Comment: see this link may be help with you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30948326/how-to-combine-two-nsdictionary-in-swift

Comment: check this too...http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24051904/how-do-you-add-a-dictionary-of-items-into-another-dictionary

Answer (score 19):

Use it like this:

1. Put this anywhere, e.g. **Dictionary+Extension.swift**:

   ```
    func +<Key, Value> (lhs: [Key: Value], rhs: [Key: Value]) -> [Key: Value] {
        var result = lhs
        rhs.forEach{ result[$0] = $1 }
        return result
    }
   ```
2. Now your code just work

   ```
    let string = "Hello" + "World" // "HelloWorld"
    let array = ["Hello"] + ["World"] // ["Hello", "World"]
    let dict = ["1" : "Hello"] + ["2" : "World"] // okay =)
   ```

Comment: `+` is a bad choice: it's usually a commutative operator, which this one here is not.

Comment: Hey @Raphael, why is it not commutative? Given two dictionary, you'll get same result with either `["1" : "Hello"] + ["2" : "World"]` or `["2" : "World"] + ["1" : "Hello"]`

Comment: @YuchenZhong Consider the case of conflicting keys: `[1: 2, 2: 3] + [2: 4, 3: 5]` vs `[2: 4, 3: 5] + [1: 2, 2: 3]`.

Comment: Hmm, @Raphael, that's a very good call! Yay, in this case, the `+` is somewhat misleading.

Comment: String concatenation (`+`) isn't commutative anyway.

Comment: Should be static for Swift 3

Comment: @JosephK sorry I missed your comment. Could you elaborate? What makes you think it needs to be static for Swift 3. I tried it under both Swift 3 and 4, and it seems fine.

Answer (score 12):

That is not possible because there can be matching keys in the second dictionary. But you can do it manually and the values in the dictionary will be replaced in that case.

```
var dict = ["1" : "Hello"]
let dict2 = ["2" : "World"]

for key in dict2.keys {
    dict[key] = dict2[key]
}
```

Answer (score 4):

You also can use Swift provided functions to do the merge:

```
public func +<K, V>(left: [K:V], right: [K:V]) -> [K:V] {
    return left.merging(right) { $1 }
}
```

$1 will take common keys from right dictionary, you can use $0 if you want to give priority to left dictionay.

Answer (score 0):

This can be done by using for each loop and inout keyword

```
func mergDict(firstDict:inout [String:Any],  secondDict:[String:Any]){
    secondDict.forEach { (key, value) in
        firstDict[key] = value
    }
}
```

than call like

```
mergDict(firstDict: &firstDictToMerge, secondDict: secondDictToMerge)
```

you will see that your  firstDictToMerge will be merged with second one without using any other variable

Comment: Theres no need to use `forEach`. In fact there's almost never a need to use `forEach`. It just makes your code look ugly. Use a for-loop instead.